# How to reuse autocalculated property in Pyventory?

Tags: python, ansible, pyventory

I have the following assets defined in my inventory

```py
class App(Asset):
  hostname = "{name}.{base_domain}"

class Service(Asset):
  hostname = "{name}.{base_domain}"
```

I would like to reuse the logic of the `hostname` property in the Service asset using its values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reusing an auto-calculated property's logic in Pyventory is possible using a class attribute as the reference to its logic.

You can either define the first asset's attribute as the value of the second asset's attribute:

```py
class App(Asset):
  hostname = "{name}.{base_domain}"

class Service(Asset):
  hostname = App.hostname
```

Or you can use a "library" Asset -- an asset which won't be used directly and will act as a library for auto-calculated properties logic:

```py
class _Names(Asset):
  hostname = "{name}.{base_domain}"

class App(Asset):
  hostname = _Names.hostname

class Service(Asset):
  hostname = _Names.hostname
```

No matter which approach you will choose the property will be calculated from the values of the corresponding class.